# Windivert ProcessId at NETWORK layer

Tags: sockets, networking, port, pid

I am using Windivert 2.0.

I wonder if I can build a map of ProcessID to 5-tuple(protocal, source ip, source port, dest ip, dest port) with a open Windivert handle at SOCKET layer and use this map with another open Windivert handle at NETWORK layer to filter/block/reject packets.

Is that possible? I can think of 2 potential problems:

1. I have to open 2 Windivert handles of different layers in the same user application.
2. for one specified socket, which layer will receive the events first? Cause I need to build the map first and use it in NETWORK layer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach is correct.  To filter at the `NETWORK` layer based on process ID it is necessary to open two WinDivert handles:

1. One handle at the `SOCKET` layer to build a mapping from network 5-tuples to the `ProcessID`s.
2. Another handle at the `NETWORK` layer to do the actual filtering.  To do so, the network 5-tuple of the packet is mapped to `ProcessID` using the `SOCKET`-layer mapping, and the packet can be filtered accordingly.

So, yes you do need to handles.

The other problem you mentioned is that, for a new connection, it is not guaranteed that the `SOCKET`-layer event will arrive first.  This is also true.  To work around this issue the user application should queue the `NETWORK`-layer event until the corresponding `SOCKET`-layer event arrives, and only process the packet once both events arrive.  This is a bit complicated, but it resolves the issue.  This is also the approached used by [Tallow](https://github.com/basil00/TorWall/blob/b8c2dc198d9eb83164beed327054de72ad1e4576/redirect.c).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll check how Tallow did it.